# flutter gradle task assembleDebug failed

Tags: linux, flutter, visual-studio-code

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /home/jerry/.gradle/daemon/5.4.1/Projects/dicee-flutter-master/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:29:13-31:63: AAPT: error: resource drawable/launch_backgroung (aka co.appbrewery.dicee:drawable/launch_backgroung) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably made a typo when trying to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
# Bad
drawable/launch_backgroung

# Good
drawable/launch_background
```